# How to dismiss a UIViewController from a UIAlertController's UIAlertAction handler?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I would like to present a simple UIAlertController to the user with one of the options triggering the closing of the parent view controller. Here is the code that I am using:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close View", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {
        action in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It doesn't have any effect. After executing the "Close View" handler the view controller that presents the alert is still there.

I also tried `self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in the UIAlertAction action block but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

instead of

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

works as required and closes the view controller which displays the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You use presentViewController to present alert. So if you use self.dismissViewController, it just dismisses the alert , not the parent view controller. If you try to hidden the parent view controller, you can create a view that width height equal to self.view and give it black color. Then use view.addSubView to add it in anytime you want.